# Open cover of the unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let

$U_1=\{(x,y) \in S^1 | x > \frac{1}{2}\}$

$U_2=\{(x,y) \in S^1 | y > \frac{1}{2}\}$

$U_3=\{(x,y) \in S^1 | x < \frac{-1}{2}\}$

$U_3=\{(x,y) \in S^1 | y < \frac{-1}{2}\}$

I am trying to prove $\{U_1,U_2,U_3,U_4\}$ is an open cover of $S^1$. I know this means every $(x,y) \in S^1$ should be in some $U_i$. I did it graphically, and clearly it is an open cover, however, I dont know how to make a formal written proof.  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $s \in S^1$. Write $s = (x, y)$. Let us consider the fact that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Because $1/4 < 3/4$, we see that either $x^2 < 3/4$ or $1/4 < x^2$. In the event that $x^2 < 3/4$, we see that $1/4 < y^2$.

So either $x^2 > 1/4$ or $y^2 > 1/4$.

Suppose that $z^2 > 1/4$. Then $z^2 - 1/4 > 0$. That is, $(z - 1/2)(z + 1/2) > 0$. So $z - 1/2$ and $z + 1/2$ are either both positive or both negative. In the event that they're both positive, we have $z - 1/2 > 0$ and thus $z > 1/2$. In the event that they're both negative, we have $z + 1/2 < 0$ and thus $z < -1/2$. So either $z > 1/2$ or $z < -1/2$.

Therefore, we see that either $x > 1/2$, $x < -1/2$, $y > 1/2$, or $y < -1/2$.

This proves that $s \in U_1 \cup U_2 \cup U_3 \cup U_4$.

Therefore, you have indeed produced an open cover.